# android AppCompatRadioButton get text if check

Tags: android

I try to get text if AppCompatRadioButton is check by button click.
this is layout :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="status"
                android:textColor="#f2ff00" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonFull"
                    android:text="full"
                    android:textColor="#f2ff00"
                    app:buttonTint="#ffffff" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonEnd"
                    android:textColor="#f2ff00"
                    app:buttonTint="#28ff1c"/>

            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

this is my code :

```
AppCompatRadioButton rb_full = (AppCompatRadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFull);
    rb_full.setText("This is full !");
    AppCompatRadioButton rb_end = (AppCompatRadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButtonEnd);
    rb_end.setText("This is end !");
    String status;
    if(rb_full.isChecked()){
        status = "Full, please delete something";
    }
    if(rb_end.isChecked()){
        status = "End, please select one of it";
    }

    bt_Search = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
    bt_Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I try get string status if AppCompatRadioButton is check by button click.
but when click button, Toast show nothing.
How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonFull"
                android:text="full"
                android:checked="true"
                android:textColor="#f2ff00"
                app:buttonTint="#ffffff" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonEnd"
                android:textColor="#f2ff00"
                app:buttonTint="#28ff1c"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

JAVA

```
 final RadioGroup rg  = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);  
    bt_Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if(selectedId == R.id.radioButtonFull)
            status = "Full, please delete something";
            else
            status = "End, please select one of it";
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want get string if AppCompatRadioButton is check, not text of AppCompatRadioButton. that mean toast will show "Full, please delete something" or  "End, please select one of it".

Comment: int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); this line return checked AppCompatRadioButton id. Have you tried this ?

Comment: I know it, but I want string status will change, if rb_full 1 is check, status is "Full, please delete something", if rb_end is check, status is "End, please select one of it".

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement OnClickListener to change value in variable Status. You can do it in 2 ways:

1) Implement OnCheckedChangeListener on the radio group itself:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);    
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            if(checkedId == R.id.radioButtonFull)
                status = "Full, please delete something";
            else
                status = "End, please select one of it";
        }
    });
```

2) The Second way will be to implement OnClickListener for both the radio button but that would be redundant code.So I will suggest you to use the 1st approach only.

Comment: in "if(checkedId == R.id.radioButtonFull)", code is error

Comment: Not possible buddy, I tested this code and then only I posted it. But as u r saying there is an error what is it? What does the IDE shows?

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected radiobutton values on button click this way,Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
  private RadioButton radioSexButton;
  private Button btnDisplay;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

  }

  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
                radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I want get string if AppCompatRadioButton is check, not text of AppCompatRadioButton. that mean toast will show "Full, please delete something" or "End, please select one of it".

Comment: what string you want to get? then put your condition inside button's listener

Comment: that string is status, if rb_full 1 is check, status is "Full, please delete something", if  rb_end is check, status is "End, please select one of it".